# How to resize and move popup's in Microsoft Edge browser?

Tags: javascript, popup, microsoft-edge

I try to move popup in corner, and make navigation to make in fullscreen, but nothing works.

There is how popup is created:

```js
function popup(location, options) {
    var myWindow = window.open(location, 'popup', options);
    myWindow.moveTo(0,0);
}
```

That's how pop up will resize after navigation clicked inside:

```js
var maxWidth = screen.width;
var maxHeight = screen.height;
window.resizeTo(maxWidth, maxHeight);
```

It is possible to do on Edge browser or not? because when `popup()` function triggered pop-up occurs in the middle of window not in corner and nothing happening with navigation icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Update: This limitation exists for all UWP applications, and is currently being tracked and investigated by the appropriate teams. The Microsoft Edge team will continue to track this as well, giving it appropriate consideration in the future.*

---

This method does not appear to behave as expected in Microsoft Edge. I am an engineer on the Edge team, and will investigate the matter further. In the meantime, I've filed [a public bug](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/8439370/) for this issue on bugs.microsoftedge.com.

Comment: Still not fixed then...14 June 2017 or Focus or moveBy or I guess most of the window.features() === "Spend more time trying to hack around something that should never have been released in it's current state."  Can't you just change the logo for ie11 to an edge logo? Lot less work.